# JNLP hangs when downloading resources

Tags: java, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

When you execute [this JNLP](http://crrcsimeditor.sourceforge.net/launch.jnlp) it 
hangs after download all resources but before execute the application. Are there any application to debug the download process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking it with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/#use) reveals..

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for http://crrcsimeditor.sourceforge.net/launch.jnlp

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
...
```

Or to put that another way.  The JNLP is invalid, expect problems.

Comment: The JNLP is valid now, but the problem remains. If I stop the download and restart it, the application works fine.

Comment: Did you uninstall the app. between testing the old & new JNLP files?